# Binding service android

Tags: android, service

I am trying to bind an activity to a service and here is my code for that
The below one is the code for activity

```
         Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
         start.setOnClickListener(this);
         stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
       {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.setClassName("org.example","org.example.ServicesActivity");
        bindService(i, conn, 0);
       }
       else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2)
       {
        unbindService(conn);
        counter.setText("Number of Binding issss");
       }    
       }
        public ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        System.out.println("Service is disconnected");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        System.out.println("Service is connected"); 
    }
       };
```

and this is the code for my service

```
             IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
         @Override
          public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("came to onBind in service");
    return mBinder ;

         }
           @Override
           public void onCreate(){
          super.onCreate();
            System.out.println("came to oncreate in service");      
                 }
              @Override
               public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId){
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
             System.out.println("came to onstart in service");
                  }
          public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
            ServicesActivity getService(){
          System.out.println("came to Localbinder getservice in service");
         return ServicesActivity.this;  
         }
              }
```

My service and activity are two different apps 
My problem is that when i am pressing start button then the activity should bind to service but it not binding and it is not even showing any errors either
can you plz tell me where i am doing error???
Thanks

Comment: Nothing sticks out at me... but have you registered your service in your android manifest xml?

Comment: @Dinko Harbinja:yes i have registered my service in manifest as well

Comment: But it is important how u registered, if it is in a different package that can make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run an activity from within the apk that contains the Service since it was installed? You can't install a stand-alone service and expect it to run before there is user interaction.     The user has to run it at least once to get it out of the "stopped" state. Then the service can react to intents. This security feature was introduced in Android 3.1.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols